# Installer information on on the recovery server is damaged, can’t download OS

Tags: macos, mac, error

[image]It wont let me download or install Mac OS Sierra. Tried multiple things, don’t really know what I’m doing here.

Comment: Well, it would appear the problem is at the server end. You could try again later. What is the current condition of your Mac. Can you boot to any OS? You might be able to create a Sierra bootable flash drive installer. Do you have another machine running OS X, macOS or Windows? Maybe Linux?